# Website registration/login process with highest success rate?

Tags: login, registration, password, single-sign-on

I'm looking for data about how to implement a registration and login process for a new website.  We are currently considering four options:

- Login with email address and password that is stored in our database
- Login with a Google account using the OpenId protocol
- Login with a Facebook account using the OAuth protocol
- Making all three of the above available

I'm looking for anybody with experience or data about comparative login rates (and refusal rates) for the above four options.

Here is what my concerns are about each:

### Email/Password

- User would need to create an account and verify their email address (a longer process than single sign on when the user already has an account)

### Single Sign On (Google or Facebook)

- Some users might think it is a scam to hack their Google/Facebook account
- Some users might not want to create a Google/Facebook account
- Some users might not want to trust us with their name and email that Google/Facebook would send upon successful login

### Multiple Options

- Confusing for users with too much choice.  Specifically, I found [this study](http://cups.cs.cmu.edu/soups/2011/proceedings/a4_Sun.pdf) that found that users try to enter their 3rd party credentials into your login fields.  They also have other usability issues in their "findings" section.

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely complicated problem, if someone already had perfect layout Open Id would have been hit! Why not try something like

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwIC1G.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

This might not be a perfect answer, but possibly first step in solving a problem.

Answer (score -2):

It is very common to have all the above so I don't think many users will find it confusing.  And I cannot stress this enough - but you need to give the option to have email/password.  Forcing someone to use Google or Facebook can make them never look at your site again.

Comment: Can you provide data or elaborate on your experience that leads you to the conclusion that email/password is  a necessity?

Comment: @Stephen: No I don't have any statistics. Maybe StackExchange have as they have lots of options for creating an account? I base it on that for every person there is an opinion. I know I wouldn't have an account here at StackExchange if the only option was Facebook...